# MVC - Buisness logic put in to external class rather than controller or model

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, model-view-controller

i make External class hierarchy in Codeigniter for my app.
as shown below.

### Class Hierarchy

[image: class hierarchy]

those classes are located in libraries folder.
whole project file structure is shown below.

Codeigniter folder structure

```
Project
 |
 +-- controllers
 |  |  
 |  +-- App.php
 |    
 +-- models
 |  |  
 |  +-- Student_model.php
 |    
 +-- libraries
 |  |  
 |  +-- Person.php
 |  +-- Car.php
 |  +-- Student.php  
 |
```

in here

model used - data handling

controller used for application navigation logic (connecting the model and the view).

view used to represent data(presentation)

**all the Business Logic put into external class hierarchy**

---

code is shown below

### controllers/app.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class App extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //loading model
        $this->load->model('Student_model');

        //load custom class
        $this->load->library('Student');
    }

    public function studying()
    {
        $Student = new Student();

        //processing done inside student class
        $response = $Student->processStudying();
        echo $response;

        //send data to view later
    }

    //process done in external class
    public function showdata()
    {
        //get data from model
        $result = $this->Student_model->get_student_data();



        $Student2 = new Student();

        //processing done inside student class method
        $data = $Student2->studentDataProcessing($result);


        echo '<pre>',print_r($data,true),'</pre>';

        //send data to view
        //$this->load->view('student_view', $data);
    }


    public function writing()
    {
        $Student3 = new Student();

        //processing done inside student class method(inheri from person)
        $response = $Student3->writingProcess();

        echo $response;

        //send data to view later
    }


    //use CI libary inside a class
    public function displaytable()
    {
        $this->load->library('table');

        $Student4 = new Student();

        //processing done inside student class method
        $tableData= $Student4->CI_GenerateTable($this->table);

        echo $tableData;

        //send data to view later
    }




}

?>
```

---

### libraries/student.php

```
<?php
//using custom libary
require_once('Person.php');
require_once('Car.php');

class Student Extends Person
{



    public function processStudying()
    {

        return 'process Studying';
    }



    //'create another nobject inside method

    public function studentDataProcessing($resultData)
    {

        $names;
        foreach($resultData as $Data)
        {
            $names[] = $Data->fname;
        }


        $car = new Car();
        $driveText = $car->drive($names);
        return $driveText;
    }



    public function CI_GenerateTable($r)
    {

        $data = array(
                        array('Name', 'Color', 'Size'),
                        array('Fred', 'Blue', 'Small'),
                        array('Mary', 'Red', 'Large'),
                        array('John', 'Green', 'Medium')
                );

        return $r->generate($data);
    }



}
```

---

### libraries/Car.php

```
class Car
{
    public function drive($studentNames)
    {

        $tempArr;
        foreach($studentNames as $element)
        {
            $tempArr[$element] = $element;
        }

        return  $tempArr;
    }
}
```

---

### libraries/Person.php

```
class Person
{

   public function writingProcess()
   {
      return  'writing';
   }

}
```

---

### models/Student_model.php

```
<?php

class Student_model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_student_data()
    {

        $this->db->select('fname');
        $this->db->from('student');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }


}
```

my question is

is this architecture correct according to the with MVC Design pattern ?

what i mean is all the processing done in external class is correct rather than doing it in controller or model ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, not a programming question per se.

Comment: If you need to load controllers with in controllers you can not do that with codeigniter MVC you need a third party HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Answer (score 0):

yes but we have different pattern design used i used kind a like this

```
Project 
|__ Controllers
|   |__ controllers.php
|__ Models
|   |__ classes.php
|__ Dao 
|   |__ sql.php // sql statements
|__ Views
|   |__ views.html
```